# How to use Kustomize and create an env like: "http://${namePrefix}service-a/some-path" or "jdbc:db2://${namePrefix}service-b:${dbPort}/${dbName}"

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Lets say I need to create environment variables or ConfigMap entries like this:

```
- name: JDBC_URL
  value: "jdbc:db2://alice-service-a:50000/db1"
- name: KEYCLOAK_BASE_URL
  value: "http://alice-keycloak:8080/auth"
```

Where `alice-` is the namePrefix. How do I do this using Kustomize?

The containers I use actually do need references to other containers that are string concatenations of "variables" like above.

It doesn't look like Kustomize's `vars` can do this. The documentation entry [Unstructured Edits](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/faq/kustomize/eschewedfeatures/#unstructured-edits) seems to describe this and is under a heading called "Eschewed Features", so I guess that isn't going to happen. A similar feature request, [#775 Support envsubst style variable expansion](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/775) was closed.

Coming from Helm, that was easy.

What are my options if I want to move from Helm to Kustomize, but need to create an env or ConfigMap entry like e.g. `jdbc:db2://${namePrefix}-service-b:${dbPort}/${dbName}` (admittedly a contrived example)?

I'm guessing I'll have to resort to functionality external to Kustomize, like `envsubst`. Are there any best practices for cobbling this together, or am I writing my own `custom-deploy-script.sh`?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you compose an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since it's hard to know what information you have available to you, what are your constraints, and *what have you tried so far*

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I've come up against one of the limitations of Kustomize.

[The State of Kubernetes Configuration Management: An Unsolved Problem | by Jesse Suen | Argo Project](https://blog.argoproj.io/the-state-of-kubernetes-configuration-management-d8b06c1205) has this to say under "Kustomize: The Bad":

> ***No parameters & templates***. The same property that makes kustomize applications so readable, can also make it very limiting. For example, I was recently trying to get the kustomize CLI to set an image tag for a custom resource instead of a Deployment, but was unable to. Kustomize does have a concept of “vars,” which look a lot like parameters, but somehow aren’t, and can only be used in Kustomize’s sanctioned whitelist of field paths. I feel like this is one of those times when the solution, despite making the hard things easy, ends up making the easy things hard.

Instead, I've started using [gomplate: A flexible commandline tool for template rendering](https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate) in addition to Kustomize to solve the challenge above, but having to use two tools that weren't designed to work together is not ideal.

EDIT: We ended up using [ytt](https://carvel.dev/ytt/) for this instead of `gomplate`.

I can heavily recommend the article: [The State of Kubernetes Configuration Management: An Unsolved Problem](https://blog.argoproj.io/the-state-of-kubernetes-configuration-management-d8b06c1205). Nice to know I'm not the only one hitting this road block.